# Juniper Switching - Cheap Lab

Tags: juniper, switching

A little bit new to Juniper here.
I am working on scripting few of our switch ports. All switches are Juniper, Ex, FX, QFX, ...etc.

I have no access to a lab to test my scripts, and was looking for one. Of course Olive was suggested but really don't have the time to maintain it.
Saw few ads about SSG-20, at low prices. I see it has several swich ports, and did my best to find out more, but do not see this anywhere.
Can that be used as a managed switch?
In other words, same Juniper switch commands (nothing crazy, basic port configuration, adding/changing description, and enable/disable) work on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smallest switch would be an EX-2200c. I bought one for my home lab. It has 12 ports and most of the important features. You can even use virtual chassis functionality (with up to 2 or 4 devices).

[Junosphere](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/nos/junosphere/) might also be worth a look. And I guess you already know about the Junos Fasttrack program where you can get the training materials for the "lower" certifications including switching.

Comment: You can also buy couple SRXs (100series)  and use them for switching, in Junosphere, I think you can use VMX for switching.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Much appreciated. I was not aware of the Fasttrack program. I will certainly look into it. I am mainly a Linux admin, but was given to me to handle, so I guess it is time to learn JunOS. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The SSG-20 only runs ScreenOS, not JunOS. Juniper switches run JunOS, so this won't help you test your scripts and test configs. Personally, I'd look for a cheap 2nd hand low end model Juniper, but it all depends a bit on your budget.

Comment: Thank you! So I was about to make a mistake. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

*** UPDATED Dec 2017 ***

Juniper renamed this product to the vSRX (virtual SRX). You can still download a trial copy - https://www.juniper.net/uk/en/products-services/security/srx-series/vsrx/

---

You can also download Juniper Firefly which is a virtual SRX device (not the same as an Olive). It has a trial 60 day license so you can test out configuring ports and so on. There will be a few differences compared to a switch but the basic commands will be the same.

I believe anyone can download and trial this. I have run them in VMWare Workstation and on ESXi server. I think you might even be able to run it in VMWare Player.

http://www.juniper.net/uk/en/products-services/security/firefly-perimeter/

There are even some articles on running them in QEMU for use in GNS3

Comment: I was not aware of Juniper Firefly. Looks interesing. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this would help in your case but:

Either from [online Juniper documentation](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/)
OR
From any of the [JUNOS books](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=junos%20books&oq=junos%20books&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.1713j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1)
OR
if possible, you could request someone to get you the Junos CLI command and their respective outputs. You can then code your scripts using them. 
I assume your scripts would roughly be doing the following:

1. Connecting to the Switch (telnet/ssh)
2. Go to appropriate JUNOS mode: config/cli/shell
3. Issue "set" statements for configuration from the config mode("#" prompt). Issue "commit" thereafter.
4. Issue verification commands from the CLI (">" prompt).

Repeat steps 3 and 4 if needed.

Most scripting languages (like Perl, Python) have libraries for Telnet/Expect.

Comment: I have access to the switch for general configurations with TACACS given to me by our network team, and use a mix of bash, expect and pyhton for scripting. The challenge for me was having a reliable lab to test, so that I don't test on production systems. Thanks.